# How do I transfer multiplayer progress from Game Pass to Steam?

Tags: xbox-game-pass, grounded

Is there a way to export a shared multiplayer save from the Game Pass version of Grounded to the Steam version? A friend was hosting the game on their end, and I want to make sure I still have all my backpack items when I join from the Steam version. There's an in-game option to export saves, but it's greyed out for my shared save.

[image: Shared world save]

Comment: Can you locate the saves under "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Maine_8wekyb3d8bbwe\SystemAppData\wgs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save files for multiplayer Shared Worlds seem to be linked to your Microsoft account. After purchasing the Steam version of Grounded and logging in with my Microsoft account, my Game Pass save carried over automatically.

[image]